# Sorting the Column Series by date order in Line and Stacked Column chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, stacked-chart, powerbi-embedded

I have created a Line and stacked column chart for each week.

Since the values are grouped by date in the week, the values are not shown in a proper order of date.

How can I sort it, so that, it is displayed in the increasing order of date?

Attached screenshot with an explanation. How can I sort the column series with respect to date? [image: need to sort the column series/legend value in the increasing order of date]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new calculated column of int values (for instance:1901,1801,1701 etc) and sort the column you want by that calculated column from the Sort by Column option in the Modeling tab.

Comment: Thanks @redmary for the suggestion. The problem is for each week, the dates are different and are repetitive, also the data is for 10 years.... so, I can't do this I guess.. But anyways, thanks for giving me an idea.. I will try to do it..